# On constructing the definition of differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definition

In the text that I'm following, the construction of the definition of differentiation is given as follows:
[image: construction of the definition of differentiation]

**My problem :** In the second paragraph of **point-2**, we see that if the condition $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{E(x)}{x}=0$ holds, *then it is easy to see that $a=f(0)$.* I'm encountering a problem here. The limit in the condition has absolutely nothing to do with what happens to $f$ *at* the point $0$.

If $f$ is continuous at $0$, then we can enforce the claim easily from the definition of *continuity*. But we're not given that $f$ is continuous (of course, differentiability implies continuity, but we cannot use that fact before *defining* differentiation, otherwise circularity creeps in).

**What I thought about it :** Well one possibility is that I'm missing something obvious and I'll greatly appreciate if someone points it out. Otherwise, I think we need *an initial condition* that $E(0)=0$, which enforces $a$ to be $f(0)$. Now we can impose the previously stated *limit* condition to try to compute $b$. So in total, we need two conditions:
\begin{align}
&1.\,\, E(0)=0\\
&2. \,\, \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{E(x)}{x}=0
\end{align}

Is this extra initial condition really needed? Or the *limit* condition alone does the job? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Point 2 glosses over the requirement that $f$ is *continuous* at $c$.

Comment: @egreg I agree. With continuity at $c$ everything looks fine.

Comment: In fact, It is more plausible to have as a condition. If you think about it, to approximate a function by a straight line at a point where it is not continuous, seems to be meaningless!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right, and the definition you copied in point 2 is flawed.

For example, simply take 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x \ne 0$} \\
1 & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Taking $a=b=0$ and hence $E(x)=0$ if $x \ne 0$, it follows that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{E(x)}{x} = 0
$$

One bare minimum way to correct the discussion in point 2, without actually specifying the value of $E(0)$, is to require that $E(0)$ be defined and that $\lim_{x \to 0} E(x)$ exists. The only possible value of that limit is $0$, because
$$\lim_{x \to 0} E(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{E(x)}{x} \cdot x\right) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{E(x)}{x} \, \cdot \, \lim_{x \to 0} x = 0 \cdot 0 = 0
$$
(in this calculation we are taking "deleted limits", since the fraction $E(x)/x$ is undefined at $0$).

Together with existence of $E(0)$ this forces $E(0)=0$.

Comment: I see that the $2$nd condition enforces $\lim_{x \to 0}E(x)=0.$ But is it always true that $\lim_{x \to 0}E(x)=E(0)?$ If $f$ has a *removable discontinuity* at $0$, which is the case for your example, it seems to be false!

Comment: I am using the following definition of $\lim_{x \to a} h(x) = L$, which is that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta) \cap \text{domain}(h)$ we have $h(x) \in (L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$. So if $a \in \text{domain}(h)$ this forces $h(a)=L$.

Comment: Okay. The definition that I did excludes the point $a$, i.e. for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta) \cap \text{domain}(h) \setminus \{a\} \implies h(x) \in (L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon).$ With your definition we have *existence of limit* $\implies$ *continuity* (which I doubt). Which version is the correct one? The Wikipedia page also seems to exclude the point $a.$ Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit

Comment: "Correct" is hard to pin down. My definition is motivated by general considerations of functions between metric spaces, studied in topology textbooks. But I agree that this is probably not the definition adopted in advanced calculus textbooks.